# Django - Render a variable which stored in database field

Tags: python, django

In my application, I will ask user to input some text with variable and store it into database. like this...

```
Url

id |     url                           |
---+-----------------------------------+
1  | http://example.com/?aaa={{para1}} |
2  | http://example.com/?aaa={{para2}} |
3  | http://example.com/?aaa={{para2}} |
4  | http://example.com/?aaa={{para1}} |
```

And there is a table with the actual value of those parameter.

```
Parameter

id |    para   |
---+-----------+
1  | 932580234 |
2  | 865234932 |
```

I want to render a html and replace the {{para1}} or {{para2}} on it.

views.py

```
def userpage(request):
    url_obj = Url.objects.filter(id=..not_important...)[0]
    url = url_obj.url

    para1_obj = Parameter.objects.filter(..not_important..)[0]
    para1 = para1_obj.para

    para2_obj = Parameter.objects.filter(..not_important..)[0]
    para2 = para2_obj.para

    return render(request, 'userpage.html', {'url':url, 'para1':para1, 'para2':para2})
```

templates/userpage.html

```
You URL is {{ url }}
```

My expectation is

```
You URL is http://example.com/?aaa=932580234
```

However, the actual html is

```
You URL is http://example.com/?aaa={{para1}}
```

How can I "pre render" the field in database before "return render...."?
Or is there any other solution for this?

I'm using python 3.4 and django 2.0

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first construct the url as a template:

```
url_template = Template(url)
```

then we render it with the given parameters:

```
context = Context({'para1':para1, 'para2':para2})
our_url = url_template.render(context)
```

then `our_url` is rendered correctly, and we can insert it into our real template rendering:

```
return render(request, 'userpage.html', {'url': our_url})
```

So that means we get something like:

```
def userpage(request):
    url_obj = Url.objects.filter(id=..not_important...)[0]
    url = url_obj.url

    para1_obj = Parameter.objects.filter(..not_important..)[0]
    para1 = para1_obj.para

    para2_obj = Parameter.objects.filter(..not_important..)[0]
    para2 = para2_obj.para

    url_template = Template(url)
    context = Context({'para1':para1, 'para2':para2})
    our_url = url_template.render(context)
    return render(request, 'userpage.html', {'url': our_url})
```

Note that if you have a rather large table of parameters, you better construct the dictionary dynamically with:

```
para_dict = {
    'para{}'.format(para.id): para.para
    for para in Parameter.objects.all()
}
```

Comment: Just added to my existing code. It is exactly what I want! Thanks for your explanation and it is clear and let me understand more about django. I'm now enjoying to use django to write my own web application!